# Python classes and methods

Tags: python, class, methods

I have online practice questions for python programming. I am stuck on this question:

```
Write the definition of a class WeatherForecast that provides the following behavior (methods):
A method called set_skies that has one parameter, a String.
A method called set_high that has one parameter, an int.
A method called set_low that has one parameter, an int.
A method called get_skies that has no parameters and that returns the value that was last used as an argument in set_skies .
A method called get_high that has no parameters and that returns the value that was last used as an argument in set_high .
A method called get_low that has no parameters and that returns the value that was last used as an argument in set_low .
No constructor need be defined. Be sure to define instance variables  as needed by your "get"/"set" methods.
```

I have this answer, but I do not know what the problem is. It keeps telling me I have an incorrect value somewhere.

```
class WeatherForecast (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.skies = ''
        self.high = ''
        self.low  = ''
    def set_skies (self, value):
        self.skies = value
    def set_high (self, value):
        self.high = value
    def set_low (self):
        self.low = low
    def get_skies (self):
        return self.skies
    def get_high(self):
        return self.high
    def get_low(self):
        return self.low
```

Comment: In the future you should post the traceback you get from the error, and the code you use to test it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't ever define `skies`, `high` or `low`.

Perhaps in the functions where you `set` things, you mean:

```
def set_high (self, value):  # Do this for all setting functions.
    self.high = value  # value is defined, so will work.
```

Comment: I did what you said and I receive this error message.TypeError('get_low() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @bw61293 Where do you call it? Could you edit your post to show that?

Comment: That is probably because you are supplying an argument when calling get_low() if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I added (self) and now it says I have given it 2 arguments.

Comment: @bw61293 `self` is passed implicitly by the instance, you don't need to declare it. Please show in your post how you call the function.

Comment: @bw61293 In other words, when you call `get_low()` you shouldn't be passing any arguments yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that high and low are supposed to be integers.

```
class WeatherForecast:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__skies=""
        self.__high=0
        self.__low=0

    def set_skies(self, skies):
        self.__skies=skies

    def set_high(self,high):
        self.__high=high

    def set_low(self,low):
        self.__low=low

    def get_skies(self):
        return self.__skies

    def get_high(self):
        return self.__high

    def get_low(self):
        return self.__low
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, in this method:

```
def set_high(self, value):    
    self.high = high
```

You are trying to assign **high** to **self.high**, but you didn't say where **high** come from, the program only have variable named **value**. So you should change like this:

```
def set_high(self, high):
    self.high = high
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing an argument in set_low.

```
def set_low (self, value):
    self.low = value
```